How to add link to an existing button on HTML
I tried creating a "take to survey" button with a link to the survey. This button only appears when two checkboxes are ticked.
I'd like to know which part of the script I should add the link for it to work. I tried adding a link to the script, but the button will not work.
<html>
  <head><title>Checkbox</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <form action="#">
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
          <span>I am a Medical Practitioner</span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
          <span>Accept Terms & Condition</span>
        </label>
      </p>
        <button type="button" <a href="http://www.google.com" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Take the Survey</a>
    </form>
    <script>
     $('form input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var Checkboxcount=$('form input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        var Checkboxcheckcount = $('form input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        if(Checkboxcount!=Checkboxcheckcount)
        {
          $('.toggle-disabled').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else
        {
          $('.toggle-disabled').prop('disabled', false);
        }
              })
         </script>

Button to work with a link

<button type="button" <a href="http://www.google.com" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Take the Survey</a> - What is this supposed to be? FYI: Nesting an anchor inside a button is not allowed. Why don't you just remove the button and style the anchor as a button?

From what I understand, you want the button to be enabled when both checkboxes are checked. This code can help:
Your code has typo issues. some tags do not close.
Since anchor tag inside a button or vice versa is not allowed in HTML 5, you can only use anchor tag and style it to be like a button.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Checkbox</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.button-disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  border: none;
  }

.button-enabled {
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <form action="#">
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
        <span>I am a Medical Practitioner</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
        <span>Accept Terms & Condition</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" id="survey-link" class="button-disabled">Take the Survey</a>
  </form>
  </form>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('form input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var Checkboxcount = $('form input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        var Checkboxcheckcount = $('form input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        
        if(Checkboxcount != Checkboxcheckcount) {
      $('#survey-link').removeClass('button-enabled').addClass('button-disabled');
    } else {
      $('#survey-link').removeClass('button-disabled').addClass('button-enabled');
    }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>



